# Quadratic weighted kappa error

Tags: spss, cohens-kappa, weighted

I have recently downloaded the extension for weighted kappa on SPSS. I followed the procedure of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_u3xnBo1Z0).
However, at the end I have the following error "some ratings are not integers". Do you have any idea about this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

The STATS WEIGHTED KAPPA extension command requires that the rating variables be numeric and have only integer values. Check your rating variable values and make sure you have them all coded as integers.